# Please:Command Not found

Tags: 18.04

```
Command 'bash' is available in '/bin/bash'
The command could not be located because '/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
bash: command not found
Please: command not found
```

Every time I logout it will have the same issue, I have changed the .bash_profile but it does not work after I make a new login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You likely messed up your `PATH` env var.

Reset it (anyone of the options):

`PATH=$(getconf PATH)`

`source /etc/environment`

If none of that works, you can just reset your `~/.bashrc` and `~/.profile` files by copying them from `/etc/skel`

Comment: Every time I login, it will output `-bash: /bin/showpath: No such file or directory
Please: command not found`

Comment: Are you not able to run any command in the terminal? Does a simple `ls` not even work?

Comment: Yes, I cannot run `ls`

Comment: By any chance do you go to Waterloo? I've never seen this error before but a quick search led to this: https://uwaterloo.ca/math-faculty-computing-facility/services/research-and-staff-linux-servers

Comment: Yes, thank you so much let me have a look